# BlueStack emulator in eclipse

Tags: android

I've installed BlueStack emulator and run it, after that I've run eclipse but when I switched DDMS perspective there are no running emulator on device window. I try to use adb connect 127.0.0.1 command in adb util, but get the same result. What can be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But in my case when i restart my System after first time installation...its works nice...